# SQL Server does not enforce encryption rules

Tags: sql-server, ssl, sql-server-2008

I am forcing encryption on my MS SQL server. My intention is to reject any client connection that does not use SSL to connect.

Here are my detailed steps :

- makecert -r -pe -n "CN=slc02xla.company.com" -b 01/01/2000 -e 01/01/2036 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -ss my -sr localMachine -sky exchange -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12 c:\my.cer
- I imported the same certificate into the trusted Root Certification Authorities Store
- In SQL Server Configuration Manager, expandrf SQL Server Network Configuration, right-clicked Protocols for , and then selected Properties.
- On the Certificate tab, selected the desired certificate from the Certificate drop-down menu, and then clicked OK.
- On the Flags tab, selected Yes in the ForceEncryption box, and then clicked OK to close the dialog box.
- Restarted the SQL Server service.

Why in the world are my clients who don't specify encrypt=true in their connection strings are still able to connect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

10 seconds google lead to:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bde679d9-ff83-4fa7-b402-42e336a97106/force-encryption-on-sql-server-not-working?forum=sqlsecurity

Let me quote:

> When the Force Encryption option for the Database Engine is set to
>   YES, all communications between client and server is encrypted no
>   matter whether the “Encrypt connection” option (such as from SSMS) is
>   checked or not. You can check it using the following DMV statement.

Clear enough?

More details under the link. And yes, nothing should stop you from using google occasionally. I just looked for "sql server ForceEncryption". Second hit had the needed title.

Comment: @Codrguy if you're still unsure you can always test it by throwing a packet sniffer from the client to the server.  The majority of the times the problems with encryption in SQL server is an improperly configured/ordered/installed certificate and not the connection from client to server.

Comment: That link is wrong. Establish the connection, right click "properties" to open the server properties pop up. Click "view connection properties" and you will find the "Encrypted". This should be a bug from SQL server.